# Securing records when it comes to editing

Tags: vb.net-2010

Assuming that there's value in all of the textfields and comboboxes. I want that when i click the edit button, there will be a pop up window that will require the users password before enabling the text fields.. is it possible? if yes? what's the code/syntax. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it possible, here i used `Mike` as a username and `Mike124` as a password, here is the code to do that :

```
'Here is the click event when the user clicks on the edit button
Private Sub EditBUT_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles EditBUT.Click
    RecheckUsername: Dim UserNameInput As String = InputBox("Please enter your username :")
    If UserNameInput = "Mike" And UserNameInput <> "" Then
        ReheckPassword: Dim PasswordInput As String = InputBox("Please enter your password :")
        If PasswordInput = "Mike124" And PasswordInput <> "" Then
            'Enable the all the fields here because the username and the password are correct
        Else
            'The password is wrong
            MsgBox("Please check your password and try again")
            GoTo ReheckPassword
        End If
    Else
        'The username is wrong
        MsgBox("Please check your username and try again")
        GoTo RecheckUsername
    End If
End Sub
```

If you want a way to store the username and the password, you can use `My.Settings.Username` and `My.Settings.Password`, **but first** you need to define them in the properties of your solution, just go to the `Project` tab in the `Toolbar` and click on `Properties`, then go to the `Settings` tab and set the `Username` and the `Password` variables.

**Hope that helped you with what you need :)**

Comment: I use different method because i got confused on how to do that My.Settings... But I got the idea from your code and it worked with the same output I want. Great help! thanks!

Comment: @FrustratedProgrammer , You're welcome, glad it helped you, please accept my answer if it really helped you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub ACCOUNT_RECHECK()

    Dim UserNameInput As String = InputBox("Please Enter your Username:")
    Dim PasswordInput As String = InputBox("Please Enter your Password:")

    Try
        dbconnect.Open()

        qInsert = "Select * from tblAdmin where Admin_UName='" & UserNameInput & "' and Admin_Password='" & PasswordInput & "'"
        dbcommand = New OleDbCommand(qInsert, dbconnect)
        dbcommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Dim dr = dbcommand.ExecuteReader

        If dr.Read = True Then
            AccountType1 = dr("Admin_Type")
            AccessGranted1 = True
            dbconnect.Close()
        Else
            AccessGranted1 = False
        End If
        dbconnect.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(Err.Description)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub btnEdit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnEdit.Click

    ACCOUNT_RECHECK()

    If AccountType1 = False Then
        MsgBox("INVALID! YOU'RE NOT ALLOWED TO MODIFY THIS DATA!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
    End If

    If AccessGranted1 = True Then
        MsgBox("ACCESS GRANTED!", MsgBoxStyle.Information)

        If AccountType1 = 1 Then
            TAGA_ENABLE()
            TAGA_ENABLEB()

        ElseIf AccountType1 = 2 Then
            MsgBox("Sorry, your access role is only for viewing! Kindly ask the Admin to change your role to modify this data", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```